# std::stringbuf in_avail() function outputs strange number, which is a lot less than the buffer size, even if no reading is done on the buffer

Tags: c++, string, stream, byte, buffer

I am working on class which will be a buffer for raw data and I want to know how many more bytes are there available for reading from the buffer (internally the class uses std::stringbuf, and writing/reading from the stringbuf is done with std::iostream). I saw the function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/in_avail/, which says:

> Get number of characters available to read

But when I fill the buffer with 80 bytes and call the function in_avail() without having read anything from the buffer, it says that there are 16 characters available to read:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    stringbuf sb;
    iostream isb{&sb};

    uint32_t n = 0xaabbccdd;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        isb.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&n), 4);
    }

    cout << "TEST size = " << sb.str().size() << endl;

    uint32_t x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << isb.rdbuf()->in_avail() << " avail\n";
        isb.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x), 4);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TEST size = 80
16 avail
12 avail
8 avail
4 avail
64 avail
60 avail
56 avail
52 avail
48 avail
44 avail
```

My intuitive understanding is that after writing 80 bytes to the buffer, there will be 80 characters available for reading. After I read, for example, 4 bytes, there will be 76 characters available for reading... then after reading 4 bytes -> 72 left for reading... and so on... But in the beginning the in_avail() function outputs a lot less bytes available for reading.
What am I missing? And what is the correct and reliable way to check how many bytes are left for reading from a buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in_avail()` is supposed to return a number of characters known to be available without blocking at the point of call. It doesn’t make any promise on how many additional characters may be available as on actual streams that won’t be known anyway. In practice it typically returns the difference between `egptr()` and `gptr()`. As keeping the read buffer up to date while writing would be unnecessary inefficient it is bound to yield a conservative estimate when switching between writing and reading.